# mysql configuration stops at "starting server 8.0.31" has failed

Tags: mysql, windows, installation

["MySQL Installer Stuck on "Starting Service"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z669o.png)I was installing MySQL installer on my windows 10 machine. During the server configuration process, it gets stuck at "starting server" and doesn't move any further.
The log for the same is :
Beginning configuration step: Writing configuration file

Saving my.ini configuration file...
Saved my.ini configuration file.
Ended configuration step: Writing configuration file

Beginning configuration step: Updating Windows Firewall rules

Adding a Windows Firewall rule for MySQL80 on port 3306.
Attempting to add a Windows Firewall rule with command: netsh.exe advfirewall firewall add rule name="Port 3306" protocol=TCP localport=3306 dir=in action=allow
Ok.

Successfully added the Windows Firewall rule.
Adding a Windows Firewall rule for MySQL80 on port 33060.
Attempting to add a Windows Firewall rule with command: netsh.exe advfirewall firewall add rule name="Port 33060" protocol=TCP localport=33060 dir=in action=allow
Ok.

Successfully added the Windows Firewall rule.
Ended configuration step: Updating Windows Firewall rules

Beginning configuration step: Adjusting Windows service

Attempting to grant the required filesystem permissions to the 'NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService' account.
Granted permissions to the data directory.
Adding new service
New service added
Ended configuration step: Adjusting Windows service

Beginning configuration step: Initializing database (may take a long time)

Attempting to run MySQL Server with --initialize-insecure option...
Starting process for MySQL Server 8.0.31...
Starting process with command: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" --console --initialize-insecure=on --lower-case-table-names=1...
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.31) initializing of server in progress as process 4428
InnoDB initialization has started.
InnoDB initialization has ended.
root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
Process for mysqld, with ID 4428, was run successfully and exited with code 0.
Successfully started process for MySQL Server 8.0.31.
MySQL Server 8.0.31 intialized the database successfully.
Ended configuration step: Initializing database (may take a long time)

Beginning configuration step: Updating permissions for the data folder and related server files

Attempting to update the permissions for the data folder and related server files...
Inherited permissions have been converted to explicit permissions.
Full control permissions granted to: NETWORK SERVICE.
Full control permissions granted to: Administrators.
Full control permissions granted to: CREATOR OWNER.
Full control permissions granted to: SYSTEM.
Access to the data directory is removed for the users group.
Permissions for the data folder and related server files are updated correctly.
Ended configuration step: Updating permissions for the data folder and related server files

Beginning configuration step: Starting the server

Attempting to start service MySQL80....................
A task may only be disposed if it is in a completion state (RanToCompletion, Faulted or Canceled).
Ended configuration step: Starting the server

.
I have already tried the following:-

- Un-installed all the programs that were in any way related to MySQL.
- Deleted the MySQL folder from C:\Program Files.
- Cleared my registry.
  and then re-installed the program
- go to Start -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services -> find MySQL56, right click on it -> Properties -> select Log On Tab AND HERE IS BUG -> Although Local System Account was selected, Somehow "This account: Network Service (with some password) was selected -> Select Log on as: Local System Account, Allow service to interact with desktop -> Apply -> Go back on general tab.
- After installing it by mysqld --install. Try this mysqld --initialize. We got the same problem but it's now working.[Admin_cmd- mysqld --install, mysqld --initialize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Dn1L.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.